# Good movie mp4 metadata editor?

Tags: metadata, mp4

I need to read metadata from one of my movies in mp4 format and to do that I need a very basic mp4 (for movies) metadata editor. Which programs can you recommend ? (Since I don't know any).

I don't need media organizers, nor anything fancy, just something that allows me to peek inside the file.

Comment: VLC can also edit metadata from Movies. Did u try it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use  [Wwidd](http://wwidd.com/) for video  file and

EasyTag (for mp4 + audio files).
To install EasyTag type:

```
sudo apt-get install easytag
```

Comment: Thanks, but wwidd does not work at all and I dont need to check audio files :S

Comment: EasyTAG will work for mp4 file format, but will not work for other video format.

Comment: easytag may open mp4 movie files, but it simply does not work properly for them ... unless my mp4 movies files all have 0 metadata I dont see this being a solution. Thanks anyway ...

Answer (score 6):

You can use VLC. Simply open the file and hit `CTRL + L` to show the playlist or from the `View` menu choose `Playlist`.

When you see the list right-click on the **list item** you need to edit and click on `Information`

[image: Click the List item]

Comment: vlc does not show the date taken for mp4 files in the metadata view you described.

Comment: also `VLC` has `Tools`>`Media Information` to show and edit some metadata info

Comment: Personally, I don't understand how VLC metadata works.  Tags that are written with it, often don't save, and tags written with other editors don't appear in VLC.  I've written tags with mutagen, Subler, atomicparsley, and ffmpeg, and the tags written are mutually viewable among all of them.  However, opening the `Media Information` in VLC, half of the tags are missing.  On the flip side, this also happens with tags written using VLC, and them seeming to disappear in other editors.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just trying to see the metadata, `exiftool` gives pretty extensive metadata on most media files, including `.mp4`/`.m4v` files.  Simply install using `sudo apt install exiftool`, then run `exiftool '-g' <file>`  This will give the metadata in a `-g` "grouped" listing.

If you need to edit specifically `.mp4`/`.m4v` files, try `atomicparsley` (https://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net).  It can look a bit daunting at first, but a few minutes with the help section, and you'll get the basics.

UPDATE:  I would add that while it wasn't possible at the time of my original response, `.mp4` editing has since been added to `exiftool`. @Occasional provides a nice example of the syntax in their response.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to install and use this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 3):

None of the other solutions proposed here worked with my QuickTime MOV file (a movie recorded on an iPhone and edited with the iOS [iMovie](https://www.apple.com/imovie/) app). VLC almost worked but the 'Save metadata' button doesn't save anything. `exiftool`, however, did work!

```
apt install exiftool
exiftool -overwrite_original -year=2020 -comment="City trip to Paris" -title="Paris" '/tmp/paris.mov'
```

Tested in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: That's somewhat of a different question.  That is, yes, `exiftool` will work on MOV files, however, the OP was specifically asking about mp4 editing.  It's also very different because when the question was initially asked in 2014, MP4 editing was not yet possible with `exiftool`, happening later with version 11.39.  Meaning, what worked for a MOV file back then, wouldn't have answered the OP's MP4 question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using the command line ffmpeg tool. This reads the metadata, displays it and edits the title.

```bash
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -f ffmetadata infile.txt
cat infile.txt
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -metadata title="New Title" -codec copy outfile.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [ExFalso](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) sister to Quod Libet music player
[image: ExFalso tag editor]

Answer (score 1):

`AtomicParsley` command line tool can set all the `.mp4` metadata tags (supports 3 tag schemes: iTunes-style, 3GPP & ISO), including artwork and long description and even custom tags (I don't know what's this, never used it).
To install:

```
sudo apt install atomicparsley
```

To use:

```
AtomicParsley --help
```

---

`gtkpod` is a GUI application that uses an `atomicparsley` library to set some metadata tags. To work on the `.mp4` files you need to turn on the **MP4 Plugin** in the **Preferences**.

---

`EasyTag` is another good GUI application that can set the `.mp4` metadata tags. It's more easy to use than `gtkpod`, but latter can set more tags.

---

`Kid3` is also a very good GUI application that, like `EasyTag`, can edit batch of files.