# Whats the best way to edit the MetaData of home videos?

Tags: video, vlc, metadata, obs-studio

I've been digitizing my home movies using OBS.  I would like to edit the Metadata Seen Here:
[image]

I've looked into VLC,  but any changes I make in it,  dont show up here.    How can I modify this data?

Comment: Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426561/good-movie-mp4-metadata-editor) 6 year old post still relevant?

Comment: @AndreasF  I went though all the programs there.  VLC being the most promising,  but like in my post,  any changes I make are never saved or they are being saved in a different location.  easytag seems to only modify audio files(mp4)